# Итератор с методами класса

Tags: c++

У меня есть класс FileSystem, и я хочу хочу сделать, чтобы с итераторов можно было выполнять некоторые методы самого класса. Для этого в итератор добавил указатель на класс чтобы методы вызванные с итератора были примерно такими:

```
int FileSystem::iterator::make_dir(const std::string& name){
    return указатель_на_FileSystem->make_dir(name,указатель_на_Dir );
}
```

метод в классе FileSystem:

```
int FileSystem::make_dir(const std::string& name, Dir* & cur_dir);
```

Создавать итератор хотел так

```
iterator(this,указатель_на_Dir);
```

Проблема в том, что this - константный, соответственно в итераторе можно создавать можно только константные указатели на FileSystem и выполнять только константные методы.
Вопрос заключается в том, стоит ли делать

```
 const_cast<...>(this)
```

и насколько это плохо. Возможно стоит как-то пересмотреть архитектуру или использовать что-то другое?

Comment: Что-то я совсем не понял откуда Вас итератор вылез в первом предложении. Попробуйте описать проблему более чётко и привести [mcve] желательно.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Если `make_dir` не является `const` методом, а указатель на `FileSystem` внутри итератора - `const FileSystem *`, то это и не должно работать. Вопрос тут в первую очередь: зачем вы сделели указатель на `FileSystem` именно `const FileSystem *`, если вам потом нужно вызывать неконстантные методы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` может иметь несколько разных типов:

- `T * const` при вызове функции-члена на константном объекте (т.е. нельзя изменять как сам `this`, так и то, на что он указывает);
- `T *` при вызове на изменяемом объекте (по прежнему нельзя изменять `this`, но можно изменять объект, на который он указывает);
- ещё пара вариантов с `volatile` (в данном случае, не рассматриваем).

Если создание вашего итератора происходит в константной функции, то и `this` имеет соответствующий тип. Таким образом, как минимум следует создавать итератор там, где объект, указываемый `this` может изменяться. Более того, не обязательно создавать итератор именно из функции-члена.

Преобразования `const_cast`, сбрасывающие константность у действительно константных объектов приводят к неопределённому поведению. Поэтому тут надо быть крайне осторожным.

В качестве возможного подхода предлагаю рассмотреть ситуацию с итераторами для стандартных контейнеров. Они имеют как const-версию, так и обычную. Т.е. существуют два отдельных класса итераторов. Надеюсь, такое объяснение позволит решить Вашу проблему.

Comment: Нашел свой косяк, когда переписывал итераторы оставил const функцию, которая возвращала итератор, по-этому this был константным

Comment: @ВиталийВолк т.е. проблема, по сути, в опечатке?

Comment: Скорее в неуверенности "нормальности" моей реализации, нежели в константности указателя, тут действительно моя невнимательность взяла верх

Comment: ??? Сам `this` никак не может быть `const`. Поэтому `this` никак не может иметь типов, указанных в ответе. В константном методе `this` имеет тип `const T *`, в обычном - `T *` (возможно еще `volatile`). Откуда у вас взялся еще один `const` на самом `this` - не ясно. Когда-то давно некоторые компиляторы пользовались таким трюком, чтобы реализовать "немодифицируемый" `this`, но на уровне языка это не верно. И начиная с С++11 выходит боком. Поэтому от этого трюка уже отказались.

Comment: @AnT действительно. Нашелся даже Ваш [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6067267/3240681) по этой теме. Всегда считал что немодифицируемость `this` должна подразумевать `const`.